# JSON Deserialize in WP8

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a `PHP` Web Service that provides a `JSON` object. In my Windows Phone 8 Application, I consume the service by doing the following:

```
public void GetSigns()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var uri = new Uri("someURL");
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += GetSigns_Completed;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}

private void GetSigns_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetSignsResponse>>(data);
    }
}
```

The `data` object within the using statement is correctly populated with the JSON string. However, the result object throws an exception (I have removed the try and catch to make the code more readable).

This is what my `GetSignsResponse` object looks like:

```
public class GetSignsResponse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Online { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Maxupdated { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Line4 { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON returns the following:

The Web Service returns a collection of the `GetSignsResponse` object.

Any idea why the `result` object within the `GetSigns_Completed` callback method doesn't correctly work? Is my `GetSignsResponse` object missing something?

The **Error** which I am getting is this that it fails to convert the JSON in to a `List` of `GetSignsResponse`.

**Update**
The Web-Service JSON looks like this:

```
{
sign: {
id: "11",
online: "1",
location: "abc",
maxupdated: "2013-11-19 16:59:05",
line1: " abc ",
line2: " abc ",
line3: " abc ",
line4: " "
}
},
{
sign: {
id: "7",
online: "1",
location: "abc",
maxupdated: "2013-11-19 16:58:03",
line1: " abc ",
line2: " abc ",
line3: " abc ",
line4: " "
}
},
```

The `data` object within the `GetSigns_Completed` looks like this:

"\t{\"signs\":[{\"sign\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"online\":\"1\",\"location\":\"abc\",\"maxupdated\":\"2013-10-05 06:29:02\",\"line1\":\"  \",\"line2\":\" \",\"line3\":\" \",\"line4\":\" \"}},{\"sign\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"online\":\"1\",\"location\":\"abc\",\"maxupdated\":\"2013-10-05 18:21:01\",\"line1\":\"  abc \",\"line2\":\"  abc \",\"line3\":\" abc \",\"line4\":\" \"}},{\"sign\""}}]}"

Comment: And where is the json?

Comment: Hi L.B. - I have updated the original post. The bottom section contains just two objects in the JSON string.

Comment: Subby how do you expect us to give a correct answer without knowing the *correct* json (not as you posted).

Comment: @L.B sorry, I think I understand what you mean now. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which the JSON was formed was incorrect in PHP. I had:

```
$signs[] = array($sign);
```

which needed to be:

```
$signs[] = $sign;
```

The latter is correct as it placed a sign object within the signs array and not a sign array within the sign's' array.